# lwt implement using minimum clock cycles

Tags: mips

I need to implement lwt instruction to multi cycle MIPS, this instruction loads data from memory into two consecutive registers. I have to write what is the minimum clock cycles to do this, write which physic changes to do and describe the instruction steps. (Data read from memory will be written to registers Ri and 1+Ri. I can assume that there exists: 30 ≤ i≤ 1)

I think that i have to do this like lw instruction and to add another cycle that in this I will lw the data to register ri+1 ( I will enter to the Alu 4 and the Register ri address in the previous step to calculate its address and enter it to write register in RF).
But my problem is that as lw takes 5 cycles. Can I reduce clock cycles? or can I use 6 cycles?
I'm looking forward to an answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is usual for the multi cycle processor to add or skip cycles as needed.

For example, while `lw` needs the EX cycle, it also needs the MEM cycle, but `add` only needs the EX and not the MEM cycle.  A decent multicycle controller knows this so will skip the MEM cycle for `add`.

---

If you're trying to make maximal reuse of the existing design, you'll have to add cycles, but as with many things, we can trade off hardware complexity for performance.

Here's the extra operations needed:

| Extra Operation | Extra Cycle using existing designs | With Dedicated Hardware |
| --- | --- | --- |
| address increment by 4 | EX | dedicated 32-bit adder for +4 |
| 2nd data memory read | MEM | Dual ported data memory |
| register number increment by 1 | EX | dedicated 5-bit increment block |
| 2nd register write | WB | Dual ported write lines in register file |

If you choose maximal hardware reuse, that will bump your cycle count from 5 with `lw` to 9 with `lwt` — that's only 1 cycle better than executing a whole second instruction (which would be an `lw`, so 5+5=10 for two `lw`s).

The 5-bit increment unit is probably a great use of dedicated hardware and can be done fast enough and in parallel with some other cycle's work so as to not slow down the overall cycle time.  Cycle count is now 8, unless you choose to beef up the other hardware.

I would probably do the +4 addition also in hardware, there's just such an adder already there for the PC increment, though I would probably not try to reuse it and replicate that hardware instead.  Still you could add a 2nd purpose to that adder with some additional muxes.  That will bring the cycle count down to 7.

---

On the other hand, reusing existing blocks like EX, for example, to add 5, would mean some extra MUX's here and there for source operands, like +4 or +1.

Each MUX added means another control line.